# Connection keeps getting reset when trying to upload file to tomcat server

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, tomcat

I am trying to create a website where people can post stuff. Currently, I am trying to make it such that users can add files sequentially and send it as a multi-part request in ajax.However, I keep getting connection reset error in chrome when I am trying to upload files. I have to log back into the server in order to see the new files.

HTML code:

```
<form id="postForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <textarea name="text" rows="4" cols="" class="form-control" placeholder="What's Up" id="postTextarea"></textarea>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" name="privacy" value="restricted" checked>Restricted</label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="group" value="family" class="group">Family</label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="group" value="bestie" class="group">Besties</label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="group" value="friend" class="group">Friends</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" name="privacy" value="public">Public</label>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div id="fileContainer">

                        </div>
                        <div id="buttonContainer">
                            <label class="btn btn-default" id="fileUploadButton">
                                Add Files<input type="file" name="file" class="fileInput" hidden multiple>
                            </label>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="postButton">Post</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var submittedFileData = [] ;
$('.fileInput').on('change', function () {
        var files = $(this).prop('files') ;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var p = document.createElement("p") ;
            $(p).text(files[i].name + " (Click here to remove file)") ;
            $(p).addClass("filename") ;
            $("#fileContainer").append(p) ;
            submittedFileData.push(files[i]);
        }
    });
$('#postButton').click(function () {
        var privacy = $( "input[type=radio][name=privacy]:checked" ).val();
        var formData = new FormData();
        //append privacy
        formData.append("privacy" , privacy) ;
        //append groups
        $( "input[type=checkbox][name=group]:checked" ).each(function(i) {
            formData.append("group" , $(this).val()) ;
        }) ;
        //append text
        formData.append("text" , $("#postTextarea").val()) ;
        //append files
        for (var i = 0; i < submittedFileData.length; i++) {
            formData.append("file" , submittedFileData[i]) ;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post-upload",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            async : false,
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert(errorThrown) ;
            }
        });
        $.post("feed-view","relation="+activeTab ,getXMLResponse) ;
    });
```

server.xml for tomcat 9

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
            scheme="https"
       secure="true" maxPostSize="-1" disableUploadTimeout="false" connectionUploadTimeout="600000">
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="C:/Users/Kathavarayan/.keystore"
            certificateKeystorePassword=""
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Comment: I don't understand, you're posting again after posting the ajax request? `success: ()=>{                $.post}` etc .. Have you read documentation ? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You're trying to upload array buffers as files, just upload the files as **files** i.e. don't use FileReader

Comment: @porgrindis sorry, that is just code to update the feed so that it shows the new feed

Comment: @musa so i just push the file objects into the array

Comment: @musa changing it to files works perfectly. However, after uploading the files the connection still resets. I have to log back in to see the new feed.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that there isn't anything code-wise that is wrong, but instead it is a server configuration issue.

By default, most servers are set to both rather small timeouts and rather small upload size limits.

It depends on what type of server you are using (nginx, Apache, Node/Express, etc) for what the defaults are and how to configure them, but that would be the first thing I look into if your connection is resetting or cutting off mid-upload.

Comment: While I agree, I suspect a symptom of something else, nested `POST`'s are red flags for me.

Comment: While it is odd, since they said it was resetting, instead of not starting at all, that's why I leaned towards the timeouts/upload limits as the culprit. Even with weird code, you can't abort an HTTP request (short of leaving the page). If it wasn't starting at all, I'd lean more towards code. Granted, until the problem is solved, can't know what is correct.

Comment: I am using tomcat. I keep getting this errors: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine and org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException. I cant identify whether it is the client or server that is resetting the connection.

Comment: Are you using TomCat directly, or via something like Spring? That message does sound like a timeout or upload limit error.

Comment: I am using tomcat directly

Comment: I'm not super familiar with configuring Tomcat directly, but here is its [configuration documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html). Looks like default timeout is 10s and max POST size is 2mb. You'll probably want to up those values and try again.

Comment: I have posted the server config file as well as put the post function after the ajax request.

Comment: I don't have enough experience to help with Tomcat myself. You'd probably be better off making a new question about how to increase the timeout and post sizes in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered the problem. You are probably not going to believe this but at the end of the day, the button in the form was still causing it to be submitted causing the entire process to mess up. All I had to do was add type="button" to the button element in the form. Now, this prevents the form from being submitted and only causes Ajax to take care of submitting the form.